# Как выполнить условие if при любом регистре букв в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код:

```
if input == 'слово':
  print('Program finished')
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы не меняя условие, оно выполнялось и при значении 'слово', и при значении 'СлОвО'.

Comment: Нельзя использовать input в качестве имени переменной.

Comment: @Эникейщик о! Кстати, да :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Привести, например, к нижнему регистру при помощи функции `lower()`:

```
if _input.lower() == 'слово':
  print('Program finished')
```

ps. Как правильно заметил господин @Эникейщик, input нельзя использовать в качестве имени переменной, поэтому добавил нижнее подчеркивание, сохранив, так сказать, преемственность и смысл вопроса